# What is the best way to link data of two sources for example by date?

Tags: python

I am writing a scipt (i.e. once upon the time) where I am reading the data from an excel-file. For that data I create an id based on the date and time. I have one missing variable, which is contained in a txt-file. The txt-file has also date and time to create an id.

Now I would like to link the data from the excel-file and txt-file based on the id. Right no I am building two lists from the txt-file. One containing the id and the other containing the value I need. Then, I get the index from the id list, where the id is the same in both data sets using the enumerate function. I use that index to get the value from the valuelist. The code looks something like that:

```
datelist = []
valuelist = []
txtfile = open(folder + os.sep + "Textfile.txt", "r")
ILines = txtfile.readlines()
for i,row in enumerate(ILines):
     datelist.append(row.split(",")[1])
     valuelist.append(row.split(",")[2])
rows = myexceldata
for row in rows:
     x = row[id]
     row = row + valuelist[[i for i,e in enumerate(datelist ) if e == x][0]]
```

However, that takes ages and I wonder if there is a better way to to that.

The files look like that:

Excelfile:

```
Date          Time          Var1          Var2
03.02.2016    12:53:24      10            27
03.02.2016    12:53:25      10            27
03.02.2016    12:53:26      10            27
```

Textfile:

```
Date          Time          Var3
03.02.2016    12:53:24      16
03.02.2016    12:53:25      20
```

Result:

```
Date          Time          Var1          Var2          Var3
03.02.2016    12:53:24      10            27            16
03.02.2016    12:53:25      10            27            20
03.02.2016    12:53:26      10            27            *)
```

*) It would be perfect, if here would be the same value as above, but empty would be ok, too

Ok, I forgot one important thing. Sorry about that: Not all times of the excelfile are in the textfile. The best option would be to get var3 from the previous time of the textfile just before the time of the excelfile. But it would also be an option to leave it blank than.

Comment: can you please give an example of the two files with one line in each and then the result.?

Answer (score 1):

If both of your files are sorted in time order then the following kind of approach would be fast:

```
from heapq import merge
from itertools import groupby, chain
import csv

with open('excel.txt', 'rb') as f_excel, open('textfile.txt', 'rb') as f_text, open('output.txt', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_excel = csv.reader(f_excel)
    csv_text = csv.reader(f_text)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    header_excel = next(csv_excel)
    header_text = next(csv_text)
    csv_output.writerow(header_excel + [header_text[-1]])

    for k, g in groupby(merge(csv_text, csv_excel), key=lambda x: x[0:2]):
        csv_output.writerow(k + list(chain.from_iterable(cols[2:] for cols in g)))
```

This assumes your two input files are both in csv format, and works as follows:

1. Create csv readers/writers for all of the files. This allows the files to automatically be read in as lists of columns without requiring each line to be split.
2. Extract the headers from both of the files and write a combined form to the output.
3. Take the two input files and pass them to `merge`. This returns a row at a time from either input file in order.
4. Pass this to `groupby` to group rows with the same date and time together. This returns a key and a group, where the key is the date and time that matched, and the group is an iterable of the matching rows.
5. For each grouped entry, write the key and columns 2 onwards from each row to the output file. `chain` is used to produce a flat list.

This would give you an output file as follows:

```
Date,Time,Var1,Var2,Var3
03.02.2016,12:53:24,10,27,16
03.02.2016,12:53:25,10,27,20
```

As you already have the excel data, this would need to be passed to merge instead of `csv_excel` as a list of rows/cols.

Comment: I guess that only works if both files are equal in respect to number of rows and order and existance of timestamps. Unfortunatly, it is not. I updated that in my question.

Comment: If entries are missing from the text file, it will still work. The var3 column entry will be empty in this case. In the opposite case, if there are multiple identical date/times in the excel file, it will result in extra columns.